# How do I communicate between sibling controllers?

Tags: html, angularjs

Here's my code:

```html
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="onclick()"></button>
    <button ng-click="onclick()"></button>
    <button ng-click="onclick()"></button>
    {{display}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondController">{{display}}</div>

<div ng-controller="lastController">{{display}}</div>
```

I have to get some message in each div when the user clicks on the button.

I've tried the below code:

```js
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.OnClick = function (msg) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("firstEvent",{});
    }

    $scope.$on("firstEvent", function (msg ) {
        $scope.display = "hello world";
    });
});

app.controller('SecondController',function(  $scope){
    $scope.$on("firstEvent", function (msg) {
        $scope.display = "hello how Are you";
    });
});

app.controller('lastController',function($scope) {        
    $scope.$on("firstEvent", function (msg) {
        $scope.display = "this is my Query";
    });
});
```

When the user clicks on each button, it should get data in each div.

How come its only possible with `$on`, `$event` and `$broadcast`?

Comment: why did you use `$scope.$on` in all controllers? you just wanted to listen in `SecondController` right?

Comment: bascially what i need when user clicks on each button it should provide some message in each independent div ..yea

Comment: AngularJS expressions are case sensitive `OnClick != onclick()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

I prefer not to use `rootScope`, you can use `intermaeidate` `service` to **share data between two `controllers`**

**Solution with services:**

**Here is how service looks:**

```
app.service('StoreService',function(){
  var data;

  this.save=function(data){        
       this.data=data;

  };

  this.getData=function(){

    return this.data;

  };
});
```

Using a `service` without `rootScope`

[**Demo without rootScope**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1H8HxGgRasnGrPq6OjbT?p=preview)

---

Solution with `rootScope`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope){
  $scope.buttonclick = function (msg) {
  var object = {
        data: msg
        }
        $rootScope.$broadcast("firstEvent",object);
    }
  $rootScope.$on("firstEvent", function (event, msg) {
  
     $scope.display = msg.data;
  });

})
app.controller('SecondController',function(  $scope, $rootScope){

  $rootScope.$on("firstEvent", function (event, msg) {
  
     $scope.display = msg.data;
  });
})
 app.controller('lastController',function(  $scope, $rootScope){

   $rootScope.$on("firstEvent", function (event, msg) {
  
     $scope.display = msg.data;
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<button ng-click="buttonclick('button1')">button1</button>
<button ng-click="buttonclick('button2')">button2</button>
<button ng-click="buttonclick('button3')">button3</button>
<br>
 {{display}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondController">{{display}}</div>
<div ng-controller="lastController">{{display}}</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wSrAlb2v3UWkFBswHePG?p=preview)

Comment: sravan can u provide that with  plunker

Comment: @pradeep, anything else you needed?

Comment: let me check this and i will get back to u

Comment: @ sravan can we dot that without using $rootscope

Comment: Make sure to remove all the listeners($on events) when you go to other states or routes otherwise you will end with multiple watchers running all over the application which will ultimately slow down your application.

Comment: @pradeep, yes we can

Comment: @pradeep, I prevented the data from going to `rootscope`, I used a service. But broadcast is needed because you are having all controllers in a same page and they are as siblings

Comment: so services are also used to communicate with controllers?

Comment: yes, they will be more useful if you have multiple page application

Comment: [here is a little documentation on services](http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/angularjs-using-a-service-to-communicate-between-two-different-controllers)

Comment: Thanks @sravan i will try to look for services

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171591/discussion-between-pradeep-and-sravan).

Comment: @sravan actually i m using ui router when user click on button it should reflect same in another  tab

Comment: another tab means?

Comment: it shifts to navigate to another page

Comment: you need to navigate?

Comment: you should have your routes setup for that

Comment: routes step means

Answer (score 1):

**$broadcast()** sends an even downwards from parent to child controllers. The **$emit()** method, on the other hand, does exactly opposite. It sends an event upwards from the current controller to all of its parent controllers.

This is a simple example of communicating between controllers

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("mainCtrl", [
    "$scope", "$rootScope",
    function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.go = function(msg) {
        if (msg == 1) {
          $scope.display = "hello firstEvent";
        } else if (msg == 2) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast("showSomething", {});
        } else {
          $rootScope.$broadcast("showGoodBye", {});
        }
      };
    }
  ]).controller("SecondController", [
    "$scope", "$rootScope",
    function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.$on("showSomething", function(msg) {
        $scope.display = "hello Something";
      });
    }
  ]).controller("ThirdController", [
    "$scope", "$rootScope",
    function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.$on("showGoodBye", function(msg) {
        $scope.display = "hello GoodBye";
      });
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    mainCtrl : {{display}}
    <br>
    <button ng-click="go(1)"> Show Hello </button>
    <button ng-click="go(2)"> Show Something </button>
    <button ng-click="go(3)"> Show GoodBye </button>

  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="SecondController">

    SecondController : {{display}}

    <hr>


  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ThirdController">

    SecondController : {{display}}

    <hr>


  </div>
</div>
```

[A complete Tour](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx)

Comment: buttons should be in mainCtrl

Comment: Each button broadcast a specific event?

Comment: when user click on button1  it should display hello in one div

Comment: Thanks @ saeed.Ataee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171507/discussion-between-pradeep-and-saeed-ataee).

Comment: can we do that without using rootScope